# IIS 8, webdav and windows file shares

Tags: webdav, iis-8

We are looking to use a webdav server to publish some internal file shares and would like to use the established security on these shares for publishing.  The environment is Win 2012/iis8

I've read and tried to follow [directions for IIS7 and 7.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2013/08/01/setting-up-webdav-on-iis-using-windows-authentication-and-a-unc-mapped-drive-or-file-share.aspx) but get 500 errors and web config errors.

I think it has to do with the authentication or authoring rules, as I can set a domain admin for the credentials or the user if I am testing with a user folder and it will go through - but that's not what we are looking to do. That seems to leave it wide open.

I am not an IIS guy and my searches for info on IIS8 are not giving me the results I need.  Any direction that may help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting a HTTP error 500.19 cannot read at //UNC/Path/web.config?

This article may help you for 500.19 Error:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

If you'll will enable "Failed Request Tracing", it'll help further to trace this problem.

To enable follow these steps:
http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

FYI: Publishing on WebDAV IIS-7.5 is slow if you are using an external storage(CIFS). And a limit to a large file size is 2GB.

Comment: I've been working with that article and still having trouble.  We are getting the second error - but can not resolve it by the noted solution.  

I have not had the time to do the suggested IIS tracing.  In testing we are now using Basic Authentication until we can get this worked out.

Comment: We're pulling away from the WebDAV and are going to work out a better avalanche solution. From all I have seen, this answer is correct and where all other options too me.